# Take element weight in a list of numeric and NA

Tags: r

Say I have a list as following:

```
my_number_list <- list (2, 4, 4, 10, NA, 30, 40, 10, NA, NA)
```

This list sums up to 100.

I want to compute the weight of each element in this list, and return another list of weights as following, but still including the corresponding NA elements:

```
my_weight_list <- list(0.02, 0.04, 0.04, 0.1, NA, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, NA, NA).
```

What is a slick way to do this (maybe in just one line of code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide every number by the total `sum` of the list :

```
tmp <- unlist(my_number_list)
tmp/sum(tmp, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 0.02 0.04 0.04 0.10   NA 0.30 0.40 0.10   NA   NA
```

If you need output back as a list again :

```
as.list(tmp/sum(tmp, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
enframe(my_number_list) %>% 
       unnest(c(value)) %>% 
        mutate(value = value/sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```